# fullyQualifiedApexMethodName in callApex (lighting:container)

Tags: apex, lightning-container

I'm using callApex method in lighting:container:

```
LCC.callApex("lcc1.ApexController.getAccount", ...
```

lcc1 - namespace

ApexController - Cls

getAccount - Method

```
global with sharing class ApexController {

@RemoteAction
global static String getAccount() {
```

This works fine in my DEV org, but in TEST org I'm running into the below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ApexController' of undefined

Is my fullyQualifiedApexMethodName correct? If so, what else could be the issue??

Thanks

Comment: https://mohan-chinnappan-n.github.io/books/lx/docs/aura_oss.pdf
s. 224 - s. 226
Please check if you have set everything correctly.

Comment: Does your container have a namespace associated with it? Also, the full org itself would seem to have a "MyDomain" namespace as well that you'd need to consider in making your call.

Comment: container have namespace?? The container is a part of the static resource, and yes the org has the namespace (like lcc1) and I'm using that in calling the ApexController.

Comment: The error is stating that "Cannot read property 'ApexController' of undefined" which indicates that the namespace "lcc1" is not defined.  Have you verified that "lcc1" is defined properly in your TEST org?

Comment: lcc1 is the namespace of the package I installed, so it should exist right? Because everything else works fine.

Comment: So the code works fine in the org where you develop the managed package but fails when you install that managed package in a different org?

Comment: Yes Keith, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem today. I have the Angular application loaded in the `lightning-container` and use `LCC.callApex` to execute RemoteAction methods.

Updating the `manifest.json` file solved the issue for me. You need to add the namespace there as well.

```
// manifest.json
{
  "landing-pages": [{
    "path": "index.html",
    // Replace namespace and controller name with yours
    "apex-controller": "[namespace].[controller]" 
  }]
}
```

You can read more on the `manifest.json` file [here](https://medium.com/@ennoucas/salesforce-lightning-application-with-vue-js-and-webpack-part-2-af0071347274).